# Login to google to download file - ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to download a file from googletrends. In order to do so I have to be loggedin. I'm using NSURLConnection so I think I have to use

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
```

What parameter do I have to set? ie how do I define username and password??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **[NSURLCredential](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCredential_Class/Reference/Reference.html)** for passing the username and password:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:userName password:userPassword persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

    [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

Please check this tutorial : [**Handling URL Authentication challenges**](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/networking/handling-url-authentication-challenges-accessing-password-protected-servers.html)

Comment: Hi thx this is great (would vote up if I could) - google doesn't require the login so I might have to find a way to make sure the connection is authenticated